# profile page of username 'admin' giving 404 error

Tags: django

My website is acting very weird for some reason.

I have a profile page that displays information about an user.
it takes username in url and pass it to *view*.
It's working perfectly fine for all users, except for the super user **'admin'**.
For example, let's say there's an user with an username 'user01'.
*.../account/user01* will display profile page of 'user01'.
But for some reason, *.../account/admin* leads to 404 error, and it specifies that it tried all urlpatterns including `account/<str:username> [name='profile']`.

What makes this weirder is, when I do the exact same thing in incognito mode, *.../account/admin* works.

Below are relevant codes:
*account/views.py*

```
def profile(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("User Does Not Exist!")
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', {'user': user})
```

*account/urls.py*

```
app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('<str:username>', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

*config/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
    path('match/', include('match.urls')),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

*error message*

```
Using the URLconf defined in futforall.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. account/ login/ [name='login']
2. account/ signup/ [name='signup']
3. account/ <str:username> [name='profile']
4. account/ logout/ [name='logout']
5. admin/
6. match/
7. [name='index']
The current path, account/admin/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: what is your base urls.py

Comment: Just edited the post to include the base urls.py and the error message!

Comment: The problem is that you dont have  either admin as user name seems that but if you do like `localhost/admin` you will get the url i believe you are perhaps you got confused.

Comment: Hm. Neither the case.

Comment: Did you make your admin account with a capital A?

Answer (score 0):

You might have created your admin with a capital A so since python is case-sensitive it will throw an error.

You could try to use the lower() function

Comment: That's not the case unfortunately, because it works in incognito mode and also, I double checked just now. Thanks for the answer tho.